# Map object holds Point(int x, int y) and colors

Tags: java, object

I am trying to create a 'Map' object.

This 'Map' object should hold 'Point'(int x, int y) objects - and every point has a color represents by a char (a letter).

**Here is a** [picture for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0GVL.png)

[image]

I mustn't add fields to 'Point'. I mustn't use Generic objects.

I am thinking of how to apply this 'Map' object:
I thought maybe it can have to fields:

```
    private Point[] MapPoints;
    private char[] PointsColors;
```

The "Point[] MapPoints" array will hold the points.
The "char[] PointsColors" will hold the colors respectively.

I didn't think it through, but I feel it's kind of clumsy and might be difficult for me later in the code.

I am in a very basic level of object oriented programming - so please consider it when you offer a solution - **it should be basic** and limited to what we've learned in class.

Comment: if you design a 2D array like  ***char[][] mapColor*** you wont need a ***Point*** class anymore..... then you can browse/iterate rows and cols to find/set colors in the map.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure I understand. My map should hold X points, Y points and a color for each (x,y).

and I can't hold 'int's and 'char's at the same array.

Comment: You don't need to store `x` and `y` at all, Store the color for that point in `mapColor[x][y]` and If you want to access it, You can access it directly.

Comment: nop... your map is a 2d array and holds the color info only...

Comment: So what would be the 'Map' object fields? - char[][] Map only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's avoid generic classes and plan on our on. From the requirements it is crystal clear that we are not allowed to add fields to `Point` besides `x` and `y` and Point has to have an `x` and `y`. So the `color` mustn't be part of `point`. A 2D array containing `char` items to represent the points is not an option either, because from a given value we will not be able to reverse-engineer the coordinates and it was clearly stated that `Point` will have an `x` and an `y` field. So this means that we have a `Point` `class`:

```
public class Point {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Since `map` has to be an object which will hold `points`, let's define its `class`:

```
public class Map {
    public Point[][] points;
    public char[][] colors;

    public getColorOfPoint(Point point) {
        return colors[point.x, point.y];
    }

    public Map(Point[][] points, char[][] colors) {
        this.points = points;
        this.colors = colors;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! very helpful!

Comment: @PillowTrip you are welcome. If this answer solved your problem, you may consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

If you design a 2D array like `char[][] pointsColors` you won't need a `Point` class anymore..... then you can browse/iterate rows and cols to find/set colors in the map, this approach has a couple of positive things

1. you dont need to create a class point for that.
2. you can set/get color directly just by knowing the coordinate where it is located...

Example:

```
char[][] pointsColors = new char[2][2];
// set color at 0,0 to red
pointsColors[0][0] = 'r';
// set color at 1,1 to green
pointsColors[1][1] = 'g';
// get color at 0,1
char foo = pointsColors[0][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashMap collection, where in you can use your point object as key and the char value(representing the color of point) as its value. This way you can keep track of your colors related with objects.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not allowed to use "HashMaps" since we didn't learn it yet.